# How to have two issued fixtures depend on each other?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

In `test_something()`, the `app` instance should be the same as used by the `login` instance.

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    # ...
    return app

@pytest.fixture
def login(app):
    # ...
    return login

def test_something(self, app, login):
    pass
```

What I tried is returning both objects from the second fixture, but I wouldn't call this idiomatic.

```
@pytest.fixture
def app_and_login(app):
    # ...
    return app, login

def test_something(self, app_and_login):
    app, login = login_and_login
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What wrong with `def test_something(app, login)` method? Looks like it same, if your are not going to change **app** from `login` fixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you described, the fixture already *is* shared for the runtime of the test by default.

This isn't really documented explicitly anywhere (or at least I haven't found it), but it's somewhat implicit: [Sharing a fixture across tests in a module](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) describes the `scope` parameter, and the default scope is `function`.

Other scopes would e.g. be `module` (share/cache the fixture for all tests in the same module) or `session` (cache the fixture for the whole test session).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't expect this but it seems to be the default behavior. I couldn't find any documentation about this though. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: It's somewhat implicit indeed - see [Sharing a fixture across tests in a module](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) which describes the `scope` parameter, and the default scope is `function`, which means the fixture is shared once per test function.

Comment: @TheCompiler Thanks, that's the correct answer. Please feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as object, and use third fixtue:

```python
import pytest
from collections import namedtuple

Auth = namedtuple('Auth', 'app, login')

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    return 'APP'

@pytest.fixture
def login(app):
    return 'Login at %s' % app

@pytest.fixture
def auth(app, login):
    return Auth(app, login)

def test_something(auth):
    assert auth.app in auth.login
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'm not seeing the behavior you describe, and I got really sidetracked by this Q&A until I thought, "It *can't* work that way..." and tested it out for myself. I tried this on:

`platform darwin -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- .../bin/python3`

I made this test, and it passes:

```
import collections
import pytest

AppObject = collections.namedtuple("App", ["name", "login"])

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = AppObject("appname", "applogin")
    return app

@pytest.fixture
def login(app):
    return app.login

def test_something(app, login):
    assert isinstance(app, AppObject) and app.name == "appname"
    assert isinstance(login, str) and login == "applogin"
```

OP seems concerned about the `app` object being received by the `login` fixture being different from the `app` returned by the app fixture. I don't see that happening. For instance, if you add some helpful `print` statements like this:

```
import collections
import pytest

AppObject = collections.namedtuple("App", ["name", "login"])

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = AppObject("appname", "applogin")
    print("Object id in app fixture: %d" % id(app))
    return app

@pytest.fixture
def login(app):
    print("Object id in login fixture: %d" % id(app))
    return app.login

def test_something(app, login):
    print("Object id in test: %d" % id(app))
    assert isinstance(app, AppObject) and app.name == "appname"
    assert isinstance(login, str) and login == "applogin"
```

I see this output:

```
Object id in app fixture: 4451368624
Object id in login fixture: 4451368624
Object id in test: 4451368624
```

...so it's definitely the same object in all three places. Nested fixtures like this "just work" for me, so I'm either missing the point of the question you were asking, or behavior has changed, or... something else. But I wanted to leave this here for others who come along looking for nested/dependent fixtures like this.